# How can I stop KVM guest from pausing on grub menu

Tags: grub2, kvm-virtualization, virtualization, virt-manager

I'm using virt-manager to create a VM from a qcow2 image that I previously created.  I pre-configured the image to skip the grub screen unless Shift is held down but the first time I launch the VM from virt-manager (after going through the virt-manager setup wizard) it still shows the grub boot menu.  Is that deliberate, how can I prevent it?

To add, I'm using 14.04 LTS for guest and host.